# How to make cursor go beyond touchpad edge?

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad

I am looking for a solution for the cursor to continue going in a direction while I am at the edge of the touchpad. This "feature" is already existing in windows.

For example, when I want to drag one folder, which is on the left side of my desktop, to the right side of my desktop; I would'nt be able to do so, because after I am at the edge of the touchpad, my cursor will stop at a position, whereas in Windows, it would continue going in that direction I wanted to go.

Of course I looked for solutions in the internet, but without success, which is why I hope to find one solution here.